# React.Children.map ambiguous behavior with Fragments

Tags: reactjs

Source code of React.Children.map [can be found on this page.](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactChildren.js)

Why does React.Children.map recursively go through Array children, but does not "penetrate" into Fragments?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like an expected behavior. Take a look at that issues:

- [Consider making <> pure unwrapped fragment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11859)
- [Children.map & Co do not traverse keyed Fragments](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13677)